# Error SSIS task: The result binding name must be set to zero for full result set and XML results

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS execute SQL task. It returns a Full result set (i.e. a table). Howevr I get the following error when I execute the package. I have correctly give a name for the returned result set.

[Execute SQL Task] Error: The result binding name must be set to zero for full result set and XML results.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 13):

There's nothing tricky in here. Just name your variable `0` - that will do the trick. Cheers.

Answer (score 13):

Respecting to @makciook' s answer, I want to add a picture of how you can do that since it took me sometime to figure out after seeing his/her answer. All you need is to double click the "Execute SQL Task", go to the "Result Set" on the left and set the `Result Name` is `0` where the Variable Name is the `object` type of variable you want to use.

[image]

Comment: Right, very obvious and logical, especially that "zero" means "0", and what Result Name is .. don't we just love the creators of SSIS and their helpful error messages .. However the documentation page of this tab is OK and 0 is 0 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/execute-sql-task-editor-result-set-page - well, what is the point of those GUIs around code and clickety clicks selections if you have to read the documentation anyway to understand what the elements in the window mean and the source code is not visible/editable?

Comment: I guess it would make too much sense to have the default value be "0" instead of "NewResultSet" for that box...

Answer (score 2):

When mapping your Result Set, set your 'Result Name' to '0' and 'Variable Name' to the variable you are using.